# C# `ThreadAbortException` is not actually rethrown, how does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

It's a long standing piece of .NET trivia that:

> [`ThreadAbortException` is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the `catch` block.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadabortexception?view=net-6.0)

My hypothesis was always that it's just a special runtime thing, where it will just forcefully insert a throw if it ever catches `ThreadAbortException`.

Now this exception is special in that it has no public constructors, it is only constructed by the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8#system-threading-thread-abort(system-object)) method. And `Thread.Abort` [is not implemented for .NET Core and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=net-6.0#system-threading-thread-abort(system-object)), it only works for .NET Framework. Therefore to actually get a `ThreadAbortException` on newest .NET installs we need reflection trickery, to get access to the `internal` parameterless constructor:

```cs
var instance = (ThreadAbortException)Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(ThreadAbortException),
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
```

But, lo and behold, it doesn't work as advertised!

```cs
try
{
    throw instance;
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught!");
}

Console.WriteLine("Continuing...");
```

This just prints:

```
> Caught!
> Continuing...
```

And successfully completes with exit code 0.
([SharpLab sample](https://sharplab.io/#gist:2cb3a7ba8d4140f43f7189f0511027ae))

My thought was, okay, if newest .NET doesn't have the `Thread.Abort` stuff, then it might not have the bit responsible for propagating `ThreadAbortException`. So let's recompile that same code under .NET Framework 4.8 and run it.

```
> Caught!
> Continuing...
```

And now I'm stumped.

Obviously using reflection is cheating and the exception and `Thread.Abort` were designed with the assumption that you can't create an instance of `ThreadAbortException` from the outside. That much is clear. However, now I have *no idea* how this might work. If it was the case that "`ThreadAbortException` is magic", then I can envision a piece of runtime code that just says

```
if (caughtException type is ThreadAbortException)
{
    inject throw code at exit from catch block
}
```

But it clearly can't be it, because `ThreadAbortException` *is not* magic. Two questions:

1. How does the automatic-rethrowing mechanism work if it doesn't look at the exception type?
2. Why do the docs say that `ThreadAbortException` is automatically raised again at the end of the `catch` block if it's false?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this? The missing forced propagation of an Exception like ThreadAbortException we had in .net Framework with Thread.Abort() and ResetAbort() is currently a show stopper for our .net Core migration.

Comment: @Marcus I didn't find any answers to this, if this is a blocker for your use case I'd advise you create an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime